# distinguish vertical and horizontal format image with julia

Tags: julia

I get the width and height property of an image with size(Image). I want to distinct between an vertical format and horizontal format image, but size(Image) does not distinguish. I tried to solve the problem with Python and got the same result with the library Image. It is possible to solve it with struct.unpack after reading the image in Python. Is there sth. similar in Julia or is it even possible to solve it with size()?

Thanks in advance,
clax

Comment: Perhaps you can check the EXIF Tags for orientation of the image?

Comment: in julia, you can check the "spatialorder" property of the image, assuming you're using package Images.jl

Comment: @GnimucK: I have checked the spatialorder property, but x and y do not change. Opening the images in windows photoview is ending up with the same result. Opening images in Ubuntu Image viewer works fine. I think, depending on the viewer, orientation tags are ignored. I agree with LuWi, but i was not able to access these tags with julia.

Comment: I thought Images.jl init `spatialorder=>["x","y"]` through [this API](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/magick-property_8c.html), but unfortunately [spatialorder is hard-coded as ["x","y"](https://github.com/JuliaIO/ImageMagick.jl/blob/e81999335e23773d9569754e9237c4e9939d19cf/src/ImageMagick.jl#L130). so that won't help.

Comment: i found this [function](https://github.com/JuliaIO/ImageMagick.jl/blob/e81999335e23773d9569754e9237c4e9939d19cf/src/libmagickwand.jl#L268), it seems possible to `getimageproperties(wand,"exif:Orientation")`.

Comment: We should check for exif:Orientation and change the spatialorder to suit.

Comment: @tholy that would be perfect and easier to handle. Thanks to all of you for your comments!

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaIO/ImageMagick.jl/pull/31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following code snippet to access the EXIF orientation tag:

```
wand = MagickWand();
readimage(wand,"Image.JPG");
ImageMagick.getimageproperty(wand,"exif:Orientation");
```

Thanks a lot to Gnimuc K. and LuWi for suggesting a solution with EXIF orientation tags (@Gnimuc K. getimageproperties() did not work in my case). To get the meaning of the returned value visit the [Exif Orientation Page](http://jpegclub.org/exif_orientation.html).